# How to transform percentage to pixels CSS for bottom parameter?

Tags: css, calc

I got this in my css file:

```
#myClass {
    position: absolute;
    height: 6px;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 66%;  <<  here is 66%
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    background-color: #666;
    cursor: n-resize;
}
```

There is the bottom percentage 66%

But I need something like this:

```
bottom: ~calc(66% - 35px);
```

or this

```
bottom: calc(66% - 35px);
```

But that didn't work!

Can you help me?

Comment: Which Browser are you using? and hat is your goal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if it should be 66% of the height, try:

```
bottom: calc(66vh - 35px);
```

or if it should be 66% of the width, try:

```
bottom: calc(66vw - 35px);
```